# What exactly is a "unit-torus"?

Tags: pde, geometry, definition, topology

I've seen references to the "unit torus" in papers such as [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.00120.pdf) (Start of Sec 3.3, page 5). So, what exactly is a unit torus? Is it just a square or cube in d-dimensions with periodic boundary conditions? I've seen [this picture](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-construction-of-a-torus-from-the-unit-square_fig6_304126129) and [this mathematical definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8956/808513) but neither seem to provide much clarity.

Comment: Does the second answer on the math stack exchange link not answer your question?

Comment: It does, thank you very much. Didn't see it.

Comment: Looking at the context of that paper's use of "$d$-dimensional unit torus", it sets out function spaces $L^2(\mathbb T^d;\mathbb R^m)$ of varying dimensions $m$.  What is needed is a measure on $\mathbb T^d$, presumably the product measure induced by Lebesgue measures on each unit circle factor of $\mathbb T^d$.  Other contexts could well give rise to different definitions based on needs of the authors.

Comment: Yes you can think of it as just $[0,1)^d$ with periodic boundary conditions. Basically if I give you a point $(x_1, \ldots, x_d)$ then for $0\leq x_i$ you would map that to $f_i = x_i - \lfloor x_i\rfloor$, and for $x_i<0$ you can use $f_i = \lceil -x_i \rceil + x_i$. Also note that your distance is also typically toroidal, i.e. the distance between two points $p,q$ is not just $\|p-q\|$ but rather the minimum out of all distances $\min_{e\in\{-1,0,1\}^d}\|p - (e + q)\|$.

Comment: They seem to be using the discrete fourier transform in that paper which assumes that a signal/image/data is periodically extended in space (it's a discrete analogue of Fourier series which also assumes your signal is periodic), or equivalently that it is on a torus.